# Check if Authorize.Net is up/down?

Tags: authorize.net

I have a few authorize.net giving forms I've built and they all function fine. That said, I'm wondering if it is possible to ping the status of Authorize.Net as soon as the page load. That way, in the rare instance that the service is down, the user is alerted before they submit their payment information.

Comment: They don't offer any kind of check so you can't do this is a realistic way. The best you can do is hit their API and see if you get a response. But payment gateways like Authnet have beyond high availability so this really is unnecessary. A better approach would be to have Paypalas a backup and if you get an error or no connection with Authnet failover to Paypal.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I wanted to be prepared in the event someone in our organization asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try querying and extracting data from https://status.authorize.net which is updated when there are partial or fully impacting incidents that result in service degradation or outages.